# table EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table EMP in my apex oracle database that contains an attribute of salary named sal. I have another table EMPSAL that has 3 attributes named averageSal, minSal, maxSal which are to be updated using triggers whenever any DML operation is performed on the EMP table's sal column. Here is the trigger used for upgrading:

```
create or replace trigger empsal_update_trigger
AFTER update on emp
for each row
declare
avgSal2 emp.sal%type;
minSal2 emp.sal%type;
maxSal2 emp.sal%type;
begin
select avg(sal), min(sal), max(sal) into avgSal2, minSal2, maxSal2 from emp;
delete from empsal;
insert into empsal values(avgSal2, minSal2, maxSal2);
end;
```

The insert and delete triggers work fine, but the update one given above gives error whenever A record is updated in EMPSAL. I have tried using `before` keyword instead of `after` but it's no use.

Comment: "update one given above gives error" - what error? please [edit] to quote it in full in the body.

Comment: You are trying to select all records from emp while it is being updated in the trigger.  You can't do that. you are also deleting every row in empsal every time the trigger fires.  I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#g1041674)

Comment: The error is mentioned in the title.

Comment: The request was to quote the error, in full, in the question body. Don't try to abbreviate or paraphrase it, show an actual example query and the exact error message that that query gives you.

Comment: Rather than use a trigger it would be better to make EMPSAL a materialized view and have it maintained automatically by built-in database functionality.

Comment: Is this another poorly conceived homework problem?  Trying to maintain AVG<anything> in a table is - in and of itself - a serious design flaw. You should not be storing values which can and should be calculated at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a *row level* trigger for this case, but use a *statement level* one. Even no need to use local variable definition through use of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...` statement.

So, just remove `FOR EACH ROW` such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER empsal_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON emp
BEGIN
  DELETE empsal;
  INSERT INTO empsal
  SELECT AVG(sal), MIN(sal), MAX(sal)
    FROM emp;
END;
/
```